# Missing URI template variable 'studentId' for method parameter type [java.lang.Integer] - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, uri

I'm getting this error when I try to redirect to a certain view.

In one handler method i have:

```
// get student ID, add it to model, and return redirect URI
Integer studentId = student.getStudentId();
model.addAttribute("studentId", studentId);
return "redirect:/students/{studentId}";
```

But I'm not getting the parameter `studentId` in this handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{student}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getStudent(@PathVariable Integer studentId, Model model) {

    Student student = studentService.get(studentId);
    model.addAttribute("student", student);

    return "student";
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you don't specify the name of the path variable, Spring tries to use the name of your parameter.

Therefore in

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{student}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getStudent(@PathVariable Integer studentId, Model model) {
```

Spring will try to find a path variable called `studentId` while you have a path variable called `student`.

Just add a value attribute

```
@PathVariable("student") Integer studentId
```

or change the parameter name.

Comment: Or keep @RequestMapping(value="/{`studentID`}", and  @PathVariable Integer `studentID` values same